# Is Nested List Comprehensions the same for arrays?

Tags: python

I created a nested list comprehension to print out some text out of my 2d array; however when I print both the outputs, my 2d array and the list comprehension return 2 different results.

How can I fix this?

List comprehension is something I just learnt about tonight, so I don't understand it that well.

My code:

```
 for a in range(int(numOfColumns)):
     for b in range(numOfRows):
#         print(Matrix)
          print(Matrix[b][a]),

result = "".join(["".join(row) for row in Matrix])
print(result)
print("\n")
print(Matrix)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to transpose it first: `"".join(["".join(row) for row in Matrix.T])`, assuming this is numpy.

Comment: By "array" do you mean A) the type found in the standard library module `array`? B) the type found in the third-party library NumPy? C) an ordinary Python list, popularly and incorrectly called an "array"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code has several undefined symbols.  We don't know what data types you have.  Manipulation depends critically on that information.

Comment: @Kevin an ordinary python list. Correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the equivalent list comprehension to your `for` loop would be:

```
result = ''.join(Matrix[b][a] for a in range(int(numOfColumns)) for b in range(numOfRows))
```

chaining two list comprehensions like this isn't something I'd expect to see or write routinely in Python, but it's supported.  unfortunately it seems to be needed as you're indexing the "wrong way around" for easier things to work.

note this is also going to be relatively slow to execute as you'll be accessing memory in ways that aren't predictable for the CPU's cache.  if you can arrange things to be the same order as suggested by @nicholishen then things will be faster — obviously not possible here

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest the second for loop in your comprehension in the same way that you have in your verbose nested loops. For example:

```
m = ['EXCELLENT', 'WORK', 'YOU', 'HAVE']

for a in m:
    for b in a:
        print(b)

result = ''.join(b for a in m for b in a)
print(result)
```